# How do I make this query with UNION and ORDER BY display correctly?

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, union

My `SELECT` queries with `UNION`'s and `ORDER BY` are not displaying results correctly:

```
SELECT printf(' ' || P_CODE) AS "  P_CODE",
    printf(P_DESCRIPT) AS "      Product_Name",
    printf("%7.0f", P_QOH) AS "   P_QOH",
    printf("   $%.2f", P_PRICE) AS " P_PRICE",
    printf("       $%.2f", (P_QOH*P_PRICE)) AS "Inventory_value"
FROM PRODUCT

UNION

SELECT null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    printf("---------------")
FROM PRODUCT

UNION

SELECT null,
    null,
    null,
    "  Total:",
    printf("       $%.2f", SUM(P_QOH*P_PRICE)) AS "Inventory_value"
FROM PRODUCT
ORDER BY Inventory_value DESC;;
```

[image]

I tried nesting the `SELECT` queries inside `SELECT * FROM (SELECT)` statements but that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

On most databases, we would use a rollup along with `GROUP BY`.  But as SQLite does not support this, we can instead introduce a computed column which places the total/summary row last:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT printf(' ' || P_CODE) AS "  P_CODE", 
           printf(P_DESCRIPT) AS "      Product_Name", 
           printf("%7.0f", P_QOH) AS "   P_QOH", 
           printf("   $%.2f", P_PRICE) AS " P_PRICE", 
           printf("       $%.2f", (P_QOH*P_PRICE)) AS "Inventory_value",
           0 AS pos
    FROM PRODUCT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null, 
           null, 
           null,
           null,
           printf("---------------"),
           1
    FROM PRODUCT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null, 
           null, 
           null,
           "  Total:", 
           printf("       $%.2f", SUM(P_QOH*P_PRICE)) AS "Inventory_value",
           2
    FROM PRODUCT
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY pos, Inventory_value DESC;
```

Comment: This answer didn't work. It gives the ERROR: no such column: P_CODE.

Comment: @Dan Just do `SELECT *` or else select only the columns you want.

Comment: Thanks, selecting all "SELECT *" selected all columns but the ORDER BY pos, Inventory_value DESC; is not working. Everything is ordered in ascending order.